# Recalculation delays are making my spreadsheet difficult to use

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, importrange

I have a worksheet with 13 sheets. the largest one has 2000 rows. I have already deleted all the possible blank rows i could.

I have also read all the guides on how to make a Google Sheet faster and still am facing issues with speed, the dreaded "calculating formulas" bars destroy my worksheet making it impossible to work on at times. Formulas take forever to update i find myself refreshing the whole tab all the time.

Three other worksheets connect to it via `importrange` to import a sheet, nothing super major.

There are a few app scripts running behind, but nothing major neither.
One of them execute on `(e)` `onEdit(e)` to look for a specific value but it was working fine before it cant that plus i tested deleting the script with no luck.

I'm running out of ideas to recover the much needed speed to keep working on it since this worksheet is being edited by 3 different people on a daily basis

Comment: Have you already checked out [tag:google-sheets-performance]?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [How can I speed up Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106809/88163)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're trying to use a spreadsheet to do the job of a database.   (2000 rows is nothing.   But three concurrent users, 13 tabs, feeding three other worksheets .. put those together and you're not in spreadsheet-land any more).

I'd suggest a review of your overall IT and business architecture, and make decisions from there about what products are the best fit for your needs.